# "Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUser' this type is not included in the model for the context" issue in ASP.Net Core 7 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-7.0

## Some info about me first

- **Computer**: Macbook Pro 2019
- **.NET Core Version**: 7
- **ASP.Net Project Type**: ASP.Net Core MVC
- **IDE**: Visual Studio Code

## Problem

If you're using a custom model for IdentityUser, you have to create a user model (i.e., "ApplicationUser") and then have it extend IdentityUser like so:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace App.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        // TODO: Write my custom fields, relations, etc.
    }
}
```

Then you go into your database context (i.e., "ApplicationDbContext"), usually located in your Data folder.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using App.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace App.Data;

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

In this instance, you're setting ApplicationUser as the override for IdentityUser.

So once you've done that and ran `dotnet ef migrations add <your-migration-name>` and `dotnet ef database update`, you run the debugger on Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or whatever IDE your coding on and have the site appearing to you.

The problem you're now encountering is that when you try to login as an existing user or register as a new one, you're met with something looking like this screen.

[image: The identity user db set error screen]

What do I do?

Answer (score 4):

You have to go into `_LoginPartial.cshtml` and change the injections:

### From

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

### To

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

### Also

On my version, I don't have a `Startup.cs` file. Instead, I have a single `Program.cs` file. In that file, you should find:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And change it to:

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Then restart your debugger, and the user part of your website should not have any more issues.